# Kafka "Exactly Once" semantics and max-poll-records

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm kind of confused about max.poll.records config in Apache Kafka Consumer regarding "Exactly Once" semantics in Apache Kafka.

Based on my research the "Exactly Once" semantics has nothing to do with max.poll.records config.

But if I set to max.poll.records=1, would it "reduce" the probability of possible duplication and the number of duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this wouldn't make any difference, as the exactly once semantic mainly to control the transactional behavior of the data being sent to kafka.

Due to the distributed nature of kafka, it was originally supporting at-least-once (in case retrials) and at-most-once (no retrials) semantic.

Below is the very nutshell definition from [kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics)

> **At most once—Messages** may be lost but are never redelivered.

> **At least once—Messages** are never lost but may be redelivered.

> **Exactly once—this** is what people actually want, each message is delivered once and only once.

Being that said, from the consumer side, whether it will poll 1 or more records, this doesn't guarantee whether these records are duplicated records or not, it totally depends on the delivery guarantees you consider in the producer.

I highly recommend you to go through the below articles, will make things much more clear

- [Exactly once semantics: Here is how kafka does it](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/)
- [Enabling Exactly once in kafka streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-once-kafka-streams/)
- [Transactions in apache kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)